# MySQL work with the database contains a table with millions of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, database-administration

I am not a DBA guy so I want to ask you a few questions.

I have 48 million rows in my table, with 10 columns.
On 7 of these columns I need to run queries like :

```
select * from `table1` WHERE `Flag` = '1' - 10 millions of rows (takes like 2 seconds) -  on Flag column i have INDEX 

select * from table WHERE `name` LIKE '%John%' - 10k results (takes like 10H) on `name column i have INDEX
```

Well I'm having problems working with `LIKE`, I need to get the results really fast without even waiting 2 seconds, in my case it takes 10h.

I hope someone here will help me, thank you guys.

Comment: 'x%' can use an index. '%x...' cannot.

Comment: LIKE will never be fast, it is not supposed to.. You might want to look at [fulltext indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) - MyISAM only before 5.6, now InnoDB too. `SELECT * ... ` is [BAD](http://www.parseerror.com/blog/select-*-is-evil) - you probably have no real use for 10 millions of results, if you wan to only count them, use `count(*)`, other than than select only fields you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql will use your index on LIKE before the first wildcard (%).
So if the wildcard is a first symbol of "seach-string", no index will be used.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html

`LIKE 'John%'` - fast
`LIKE '%John%'` - slow

i believe u should use full-text search

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html